# Unable to understand certain concepts in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope

In the [website](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp) the following lines are given:

> Your global variables (or functions) can overwrite window variables (or functions).
> Any function, including the window object, can overwrite your global variables and functions.

I am unable to understand what this says.

Comment: Find a different tutorial.  That's a really weird way to explain the concept of the global scope.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's distinguishing between variables and functions. Functions are stored inside variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above that paragraph you can find this:

> Global Variables in HTML
>   With JavaScript, the global scope is the complete JavaScript environment.
>
> In HTML, the global scope is the window object. All global variables belong to the window object.

Combined with the quote in your question - it means that because the global scope is actually the `window` object - it's possible to override global functions/variables.

Here is an example:

```js
console.log(window.Math.PI);

Math = {
  PI: 5
}

console.log(Math.PI);
```

Comment: First it is saying global variable can override window variable and then it is saying window object can over ride global variable. The opposite. Quite confusing

Comment: The important sentence there is "In HTML, the **global scope is the window** object. All global variables **belong to the window object**."

Comment: Then what's the purpose of saying global variable can override global variable?

Comment: When you define a variable/function in the global scope - you can override the window functions/variable. It's important to understand this. The language there might not be perfect, but it's correct.

Comment: Can you please write an answer by correcting whatever confusion that is present in the said language?

Comment: I really do think that my answer gives exactly that (with the example above)

Answer (score 2):

The browser puts certain "global" (i.e. accessible anywhere in any file) functions and variables on the `window` object. One such example is the function `window.setTimeout`, which executes its argument after a given delay.

You can also access these global `window.*` variables without the window prefix at all, i.e.

```
window.setTimeout === setTimeout
```

That means if you assign to a global variable with a conflicting name, you can 'override' the browser defaults -

```
window.setTimeout === setTimeout
setTimeout = 'myString'
window.setTimeout === 'myString'
```

That's why it's generally best practice not to create variables in the global (`window`) scope.